# SSRS not rendering all page breaks in PDF export

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report is ssrs, it consist of a main report which has a header containing the page number and 2 sub reports (report page 1 and report page 2) within a tablix.  Report page one comes first, then report page 2 displays on the next page after the end of report page 1.  The subreports can be anywhere from 1-3 pages.  The page numbering is reset between each set of report page 1 and 2 (so if page 1 is 3 pages and page 2 is 2 pages, it goes from page 1-5, then resets).  These are called for each record (with grouping) from the main reports' query.  The report is around 1000 pages total.  It renders perfectly on screen, but when I try to export to PDF, it will sometimes (like 1 time in the 1000 pages) display part of report page 2 on a page (as expected, the page number matches with it), then it will start printing report page 1 of the next group on the same page.

Here is the layout of the main report:
[image: 1]

Here is the document outline for better understanding:
[image: 2]

And here is the page that is wrong...
[image: 3]

This is what it should look like (the last page of sub-report page 2 even has just the total record like the broken one!
[image: 4]

I have tried everything I can think of.  I have tried (i think) every combination of page breaks on the rectangles and groups, I have tried making a tablix with 2 rows using the same group and again tried every combination of page breaks.  I have tried changing the number of records on a page.  I have tried changing the consume whitespace option on both sub and main reports.  I have tried adding both calculated and random amounts of white space.  I have recreated the report from scratch a couple times.  I'm sure there's more, but it would be like going through a full feature list of SSRS...  Basically, I tried everything I could think of, then everything suggested in the links on the first page of about 10 different google searches.  I just have no idea what is going on with this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Let me know if you need any more info, screenshots, or whatever and I will try to provide.  It may be highly "redacted", but I will provide anything I can.

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Try check the setting "Between each instance of a group" in group properties of tablix.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your XML for empty TablixRows (which will not show up in the Document Outline). I found with my report that empty tablix rows screw up page breaks in subsequent rows / sub reports when exported to PDF. Where possible hide the TablixRows or insert and empty text box.

This appears to be a bug with SSRS when editing the XML by hand. The Visual Studio GUI seems to not let you delete the last element in a row - perhaps this is a work around. An error or schema validation message would have been nice for us hand coders!

Hope this helps.